# Upon DoubleClick, all DataGridViewRow cells of a row must load as textboxes in another form

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and to SO.

I have 2 forms. Form 1 has to capture some primary information for a single item like description, price, EAN code and so on (each in a textbox).

I have a second form named SearchForm containing a search textbox to search with and load a DataGridView with the results upon selection by double click or row selection. This in turn should show the data loaded into the Form 1.

Now is the question.
When I select a row in the search form, Search form should hide and Form1 should load with the necessary info.

which one is better to use CellContentClick or CellDoubleClick?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Add your code what you tried and let us know error if any.

Comment: CellContentclick is not recommended because it is easy to miss the actual content. SelectionChanged is often used, other event will also work.